# How do I complete 'The Devil' fortune?

Tags: pine-tar-poker

In Pine Tar Poker, one of the fortunes is The Devil. The text reads 'THE DEVIL IS SURROUNDED BY **TWO KINGS WITH THE MARK OF THE BEAST.**' How is this fortune completed?

Answer (score 1):

The hand that I successfully completed this with was a Full House using K♦, 6♦, K♣, 6♥, 6♦. Both K♣ and 6♦ were created with runes.

[image]

My best theory is that that The Devil requires a full house made out of 2 Kings and 3 sixes (666 being the mark of the beast).